# .Net Core OData Default Select

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata

I am using .Net Core 2.2 OData in our project. I want to use default select query for an entity because I have sentive data for users and users can decide to share or not.

```
public IQueryable<User> Get()
{
    return db.Users.Where(x => x.ShowProfile).Select(x => new User
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Surname = x.Surname,
        Photo = x.ShowPhoto && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Photo) ? x.Photo : null,
        Bar = x.Bar,
        RegistrationNumber = x.RegistrationNumber,
        PhoneNumber = x.ShowPhoneNumber && x.PhoneNumber != "-" ? x.PhoneNumber : null,
        WorkPhoneNumber = x.ShowWorkPhoneNumber && x.WorkPhoneNumber != "-" ? x.WorkPhoneNumber : null,
        Email = x.ShowEmail && x.Email != "-" ? x.Email : null,
        //Profiles = x.Profiles //Error When This Line Uncommented
    }).AsQueryable();
}
```

This code works well but if I use $expand and $filter for expand then I can't get a result and I need it.

I have tried an DTO model as UserDto and this is work well but result is not odata format and I can't use $count etc.

What is the correct way to apply?

Comment: I found this to be a good read about OData https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreOData please check that you have all the right settings enabled on the project's startup as well on the API endpoint

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have readed this. But I can't find any result for my problem.